# Control Samsung Smart TV (Infrared Remote) via Hue / Zigbee?

Tags: zigbee, samsung-smartthings, philips-hue, infrared

Is there any possible way to remote control my Samsung Smart TV (which has an infrared remote) via my Philips Hue system, which communicates over Zigbee?

It seems like ORVIBO is producing such stuff, but I can't find any further information, nor a retailer in Germany. I would like to tell Alexa/Siri to "Switch on my TV", which then triggers another device to send the "switch on" signal via infrared. A Zigbee plug is not an option for me, as it would switch off the TV hard.

Using Hue would be optimal as I use it for everything, but any idea of achieving this in any way would be nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Logitech Harmony Hub](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/harmony-hub?crid=60) is a smart hub that can control devices via infrared (like your TV remote), and is [compatible with Alexa](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/harmony-hub/page/harmony-alexa).  It doesn't work via ZigBee, though — it connects via Wi-Fi to your Echo instead.

You can see if it's compatible with your device on the [compatibility page](https://support.myharmony.com/en-gb/compatibility); as of writing, Logitech claim that the hub is compatible with over 270,000 devices, so I suspect your TV should be supported.

Alternatively, you could consider one of various other infrared skills and hubs compatible with Alexa, such as [this skill](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B018YICXQS) which can use a phone with an IR blaster to send the necessary signals. I think you're less likely to find something specifically designed to work with the Hue's network for this purpose, and Wi-Fi based devices are a little more common. The Harmony is the one that is probably most well-known and compatble at the moment.